# Inserting data from multipledict into multiple rows using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, pyramid

Assuming I have a table with the following columns:

```
id, title, description
```

I have a form with multiple input fields with the same names. E.g.:

```
<input type='text' name='title' value = 'A title' />
<input type='text' name='title' value = 'Another title' /> etc...
```

I get the following multidict from the POST request.

```
([('title', 'A title'), ('description', 'A description'), 
('title', 'Another title'), ('description', 'Another description'), 
('title', 'One more title'), ('description', 'One more description')])
```

My question is, from the data above how would I seperate each row of data from the multidict above and do an 'INSERT INTO' using SQLAlchemy, so data is inserted into multiple rows in the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following (self-contained working sample) code should give you the idea:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True,)
metadata = MetaData()

mytable = Table('mytable', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('title', String(50)),
    Column('description', String(50)),
)

class MyObject(object):
    # 1. define keywork based constructor (or do this in the part 2.)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

mapper(MyObject, mytable)
metadata.create_all(engine)

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)()

input = ([('title', 'A title'), ('description', 'A description'), 
('title', 'Another title'), ('description', 'Another description'), 
('title', 'One more title'), ('description', 'One more description')])

# 2. add data to the session, then commit
while input:
    values = dict((input.pop(0), input.pop(0)))
    obj = MyObject(**values)
    session.add(obj)
session.commit()
```

Comment: There's also `session.add_all(list_of_objects)`

Comment: This is great! It gives me a really good idea on how to deal with such a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use `multidict.getall()` and `zip` to achieve the same in my code:

```
...
input = ([('title', 'A title'), ('description', 'A description'), 
          ('title', 'Another title'), ('description', 'Another description'), 
          ('title', 'One more title'), ('description', 'One more description')])

titles = input.getall('title')
descriptions = input.getall('description')
for title, description in zip(titles, descriptions):
    obj = MyObject(title, description)
    session.add(obj)
...
```

It seems a bit more clear but I don't know about other advantages/disadvantages.